# Rendering data in FlatList from firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I am using React Native 0.49. I have data fetched from firebase, list of users `users/`, each item in this list was set like this `firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set(userInfo)` userId is the `uid` of the currentUser.

Now I am fetching back (in actions - redux):

```
export function getPeople(){
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(getPeopleRequest());
        getData().then(result => {
            dispatch(getPeopleSuccess(result.val()))
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(getPeopleFailure(error))
        }); 
    }
}

const getData = () => {
    const userRef = firebase.database().ref('users/').limitToFirst(20);
    return userRef.once('value');     
}
```

In component, I am trying to render the data in FlatList, but it's not rendering anything, I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.props.getPeople();
}
_renderItem = ({ item }) => (

    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
    </View>
);

render(){
    const { inProgress, people, error } = this.props.peopleData;
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={people}
            renderItem={this._renderItem} 
        />
    );
}
```

when console log `people` this is result:
`{cpycwkz7exVBzmhaLEtHjMW66wn1: {…}, UbIITfUANmb63cYE2x7dZRZ0pfK2: {…}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FlatList` component expects its `data` prop to be an array. You are passing it as an Object. You can change it to an array of Objects. Then too in your `_renderItem` method the `item` will be an object and it can't be rendered straight away in `<Text>`, you have to extract a text value from the item object and than render it as: `<Text>SOME_TEXT_NOT_AN_OBJECT</Text>`

You can convert your people object to an array and pass it to the `<FlatList` like this:

```
render(){
    const { inProgress, people, error } = this.props.peopleData;
    let ArrayOfPeopleObject = Object.values(people)
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={ArrayOfPeopleObject}
            renderItem={this._renderItem} 
        />
    );
}
```

Now each `item` in the `_renderItem` method will be an object and you can extract value from any key and render it in the `<Text>`.

Answer (score 3):

Flatlist data requires a key for each object in the array you can convert the firebase result like this:

```
Object.entries(peopleFromFirebase).map(item => ({...item[1], key: item[0]}));
```

So json from firebase like this:

```
{
  cpycwkz7exVBzmhaLEtHjMW66wn1: {
    name: 'wade owen watts', 
    phone:'+447...'
  }, 
  UbIITfUANmb63cYE2x7dZRZ0pfK2: {
    name: 'Helen Harris', 
    phone:'+448...'
  }
}
```

becomes:

```
[
  {
    key: 'cpycwkz7exVBzmhaLEtHjMW66wn1',
    name: 'wade owen watts', 
    phone:'+447...'
  }, 
  {
    key:'UbIITfUANmb63cYE2x7dZRZ0pfK2',
    name: 'Helen Harris', 
    phone:'+448...'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Flat list except array of objects but the firebase return the data as map like {key: value} pair so you should transform this map to array , you can install lodash module and use _.values() function to do that

Comment: where do I put that piece of code? in `getData()` function ? Or do I do that in the reducer ?