# Rendering Firebase User Profiles with FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am new to react-native and javascript in general, and I am trying to render some firebase data into a flatlist. My firebase data is set up like this:

```
profiles:
    0:
     first: John
     last: Doe
     picture: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/4.jpg"
   ...
```

I've followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6 
for setting up the flatlist, but now, i'm trying to modify the data so that instead of using randomly generated user data, it pulls the information from firebase.

the general area of code where the data is being fetched is this:

```
class FlatListDemo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

this.state = {
  loading: false,
  data: [],
  page: 1,
  seed: 1,
  error: null,
  refreshing: false
};

}
componentDidMount() {
this.makeRemoteRequest();
}

makeRemoteRequest = () => {
const { page, seed } = this.state;
const url = `https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=${seed}&page=${page}&results=20`;
this.setState({ loading: true });

fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      data: page === 1 ? res.results : [...this.state.data, ...res.results],
      error: res.error || null,
      loading: false,
      refreshing: false
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.setState({ error, loading: false });
  });
 };
```

...

```
  render() {
return (
  <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <ListItem
          roundAvatar
          title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
          subtitle={item.email}
          avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
          containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
        />
      )}
      keyExtractor={item => item.email}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
      ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
      ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
      onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
      refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
      onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={50}
    />
  </List>
);
   }
 }
```

Like i said, i'm very new to both react-native and js in general, so any help that i can get to save me from a billion google searches, i would appreciate

Comment: What have you tried in terms of making an api call to your firebase db? Or are you wanted to add listeners that will update dynamically?

Comment: I've tried modifying it based on answers like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47009264/rendering-data-in-flatlist-from-firebase 

but I'm having trouble understanding how that fits into my code, in particular, without having to change too much. I might want more dynamically updating stuff later, but for now, I really just want the information to be pulled from firebase and just displayed in a list